# GWT DataGrid wont display and an exception is thrown (only in Google Chrome)

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt, datagrid

I try to convert from CellTable to DataGrid and I cant seem to make even the most trivial code work.

I have the following entry point:

```
public class Main implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(genDataGrid());
    }

    private Widget genDataGrid() {
        DataGrid<String> dataGrid = new DataGrid<String>();

        dataGrid.setWidth("100%");
        dataGrid.setHeight("100px");

        dataGrid.setAutoHeaderRefreshDisabled(true);

        dataGrid.addColumn(new TextColumn<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(String object) {
                return object;
            }}, "Caption 1");
        dataGrid.addColumn(new TextColumn<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(String object) {
                return object;
            }}, "Caption 2");

        return dataGrid;
    }
}
```

when I run this simple code I get a blank screen with the following exception:

```
Uncaught com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException: Exception caught: (ReferenceError) : Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_IsWidget_2_classLit_0_g$ is not defined
AttachDetachException.java:87   tryCommand_1_g$
Panel.java:129   doAttachChildren_2_g$
Widget.java:354   onAttach_2_g$
HeaderPanel.java:167   onAttach_15_g$
Composite.java:179   onAttach_3_g$
Widget.java:484   setParent_0_g$
Panel.java:124   adopt_1_g$
LayoutPanel.java:198   insert_13_g$
LayoutPanel.java:134   add_31_g$
Main.java:126   onModuleLoad_3_g$
com_00046heartbeattec_00046app_00046medibeat_00046www_00046StaticPatientDataPortal__EntryMethodHold…:3   init_3_g$
ModuleUtils.java:44   initializeModules_0_g$
Impl.java:247   apply_0_g$
Impl.java:306   entry0_0_g$
Impl.java:72   (anonymous function)
ModuleUtils.java:55   gwtOnLoad_0_g$
Map.java:29   (anonymous function)
```

(the line `Main.java:126   onModuleLoad_3_g$` refers to the line `RootLayoutPanel.get().add(genDataGrid());` in the code above)

I have no idea what is causing this exception and when I change it from DataGrid to CellTable it works fine.

I use GWT 2.7.0

EDIT:
I just found out that this only happens in Google Chrome browser. Any idea why ?

Comment: I had the same issue, that's why I landed here. I tried to populate the data in a REST callback, but the table remained empty. When I insert static data first (in this case "loading..."), the table is rendered and shows the data from the REST call when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after investigating, I noticed that the exception is coming from `doAttachChildren` and `doDetachChildren` in `CustomScrollPanel`.

For example, in `doAttachChildren`, the call to `AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.attachCommand, getWidget(), hScrollbar,vScrollbar);` fails and this is coming from the varargs part of the method.

Here is a workaround for those methods:

```
  @Override
  protected void doAttachChildren() {
    List<Widget> list = new ArrayList<Widget>();
    list.add(getWidget());
    list.add(hScrollbar.asWidget());
    list.add(vScrollbar.asWidget());
//  AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.attachCommand, getWidget(), hScrollbar, vScrollbar);
    AttachDetachException.tryCommand(list, AttachDetachException.attachCommand);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doDetachChildren() {
      List<Widget> list = new ArrayList<Widget>();
      list.add(getWidget());
      list.add(hScrollbar.asWidget());
      list.add(vScrollbar.asWidget());
//    AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.detachCommand, getWidget(), hScrollbar, vScrollbar);
    AttachDetachException.tryCommand(list,AttachDetachException.detachCommand);
  }
```

Comment: Hey. I've tried Your solution, but I dont have such variables: `vScrollbar` and `vScrollbar`. Can You help me?

Comment: Hi, I suppose you tried to extend CustomScrollPanel. In this case, it's normal you cannot see the attributes because they are private. Try to use `getHorizontalScrollbar()` for `hScrollbar` and `getVerticalScrollbar()` for `vScrollbar`

Comment: I get that this is a "workaround", but since the CustomScrollPanel is used/instantiated deep within the DataGrid in GWTs libraries, I do not see how this is a workaround? If the above code works, this should be accepted as a bug in GWT right away.
If anyone has a real workaround, like, how to get this to work in v2.7.0, I'd be really interested in hearing it.

Comment: I don't provide code that I didn't check myself. Here is how to get it working : you only have to copy the source of `CustomScrollPanel`in your project (same package, same class name), do the modifications, and as for most projects, the classloader will load your class and not the one in GWT libraries. I didn't submit that code because the real problem is for me in the transpilation to Javascript as it is working in other browsers

Comment: I am having the same problem - but unfortunately even when I do exactly as you suggest it still doesn't work. I see this:
uncaught exception: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException: Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: (ReferenceError) : Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_IsWidget_2_classLit_0_g$ is not defined
uncaught exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Should only call onDetach when the widget is attached to the browser's document

Comment: Are you sure you got exactly the same code because I suppose you want first to show the widget, so I don't understand how you could end up with a "Should only call onDetach" Exception? you should check your `doAttachChildren` method, that you use `AttachDetachException.attachCommand` in  `tryCommand`